# Extracting list of layers in MXD using ArcGIS Desktop and Python?

Tags: arcpy, layers, arcgis-9.3, mxd

I have been trying to extract a list of all the layers in my mxd (ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1), using Python 2.5. If I could have the source of the layers too that would be even better... But as long as I can get a list of all the layers I have in my mxd that would be so handy!

I have seen several scripts but they are all "arcpy" , which as far as I understood only ArcGIS Desktop 10, unfortunately upgrading is not possible right now. there is very little on 9.3.1.

I am a somehow new to Python but I am confident we will find  a work around for that.

Answer (score 3):

The functionality to [list layers](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000002n000000) in an MXD only became available with the introduction of the ArcPy site-package and its `arcpy.mapping` module at ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Using `arcgisscripting` to [list datasets](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Listing_data) at ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 was straightforward but the Python bindings for ArcGIS needed significant development before layers would become understandable to them as well.

If meeting this requirement is mandatory then your only option is to upgrade to at least ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.